# Connecting To mydomain.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed

Tags: centos, iptables

I have these settings in /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

I think i should have 25 port open , and i rebooted my machine , but i got error "Connecting To mydomain.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed"
"telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused" by running "telnet mail.mydomain.com 25"

i tested locally by running 'telnet localhost 25', it was running fine . I got "220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix"

Something else I need to configure to open port 25?

This is Centos 5.4

Thanks

Comment: Is there something bound to that port? Where are you connecting from/to? Can you connect to the other ports?

Comment: i think postfix is using this post? I like to telnet to test postfix

Comment: I can connect to ssh post 22 no problem and httpd port 80

Comment: Don't think. Use `netstat` to verify.

Comment: when i ran netstat -an I got this "tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN "  does it look right?

Comment: by the way i tested locally by running 'telnet localhost 25', it was running fine . I got "220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to see if you have a firewall sitting in front of this host preventing incoming port 25? The rules you have listed should definitely let you in. In fact, you have port 25 allowed twice.

On a side note, you should keep your rules consistent with Red Hat/CentOS's conventions. These rules:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
```

Should look like this, placed after the `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` line like so:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Also, make sure you run `/etc/init.d/iptables restart` after making changes to this file. To confirm if they've been applied, run:

```
# iptables -L -n | grep 25
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:25
```

Good Luck.

Comment: thanks , i do see "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:25
"

Comment: In this case, there's nothing on your local server that should be preventing you from taking incoming connections on port 25. It's likely a firewall sitting in front of your machine. You may want to contact your service provider to confirm.

Comment: thanks! problem solved , it was because the setting in my postfix main.cf. I changed "inet_interfaces = localhost" to "inet_interfaces = $myhostname
"

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio mentioned, you might want to be sure that Postfix is actually listening on that port, and accepting connections.  It might simply be that it's configured to send mail via port 25, and not accept it.  Some commands for that:  `netstat -an` to see what's listening.  Something better be listed on port 25 for telnet to connect.  Look into `tcpdump` to actually capture packets on the server, and see if your telnet is getting through or not.  Likewise, you might want to turn on iptables logging to make sure that really is what's killing your packets.


--Christopher Karel

Comment: when i ran netstat -an I got this "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
"

Comment: by the way i tested locally by running 'telnet localhost 25', it was running fine . I got "220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix"

Comment: thanks! problem solved , it was because the setting in my postfix main.cf. I changed "inet_interfaces = localhost" to "inet_interfaces = $myhostname "